# Exponential growth of a combinations expression

Tags: exponential-function, combinations

Assume $K,K\cdot a$ positive integers with $K\cdot a< K$. I have the expression $\binom{K}{K\cdot a}$ and the author says that it grows exponentially with $K$ when $a$ is fixed. Why is that?

Comment: By $Ka$ do you mean the product $K\times a$ or $K_a$, a distinct integer from $K$?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I have made an edit to clarify that it's actually a product

Comment: Are both $K$ and $Ka$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: @Mark Yes, they are

Comment: what about $a=1$...

Comment: I don't think $a$ has to be an integer (so as an example, $K = 8, a = 2$ might work).

Comment: @Rustyn I guess I'll have to make a lot of edits. Please see above. Let's stick to the case of strict inequality

Comment: @Mark First, I did not say that $a$ has to be an integer, $K\cdot a$ has to  be. Second, in your example you set $a$ as an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to explain this is probably via Stirling's approximation to the factorial.

Stirling's approximation is
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
Recalling that
$$
\binom{K}{Ka}=\frac{K!}{(Ka)!(K(1-a))!},
$$
this implies
$$
\begin{align*}
\binom{K}{Ka}&\sim\sqrt{\frac{2\pi K}{4\pi^2KaK(1-a)}}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{K}{e}\right)^K}{\left(\frac{Ka}{e}\right)^{Ka}\left(\frac{K(1-a)}{e}\right)^{K(1-a)}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi Ka(1-a)}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{a^a(1-a)^{1-a}}\right)^K\\
&=C\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\cdot D^K
\end{align*}
$$
with $C$ and $D$ constants (depending on $a$) defined in the obvious way.

Now, because $Ka<K$, we have $a\in(0,1)$. (We must have $a>0$; $a=0$ does not yield exponential growth here.)  You can verify that this implies $1< D\leq 2$, so that this is an exponentially growing function.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a hint on the proof of $D\geq2$?

Comment: That's equivalent to showing that $a^a(1-a)^{1-a}\leq\frac{1}{2}$.  To that end: take the logarithm to get $a\ln(a)+(1-a)\ln(1-a)$.  You can find the maximum of this by differentiation; then, you can finish using monotonicity of the exponential.

Comment: Hmm... hold on a sec.  I've made a mistake here.  $a^a(1-a)^{1-a}$ has a MINIMUM of $\frac{1}{2}$.  One sec.

Comment: Alright, fixed.  And you can show it by showing the minimum of $\frac{1}{2}$, as described above, combined with $a^a(1-a)^{1-a}<1$.

Comment: OK, I have made some calculations here. So, for the first part $D\leq2$ we have $\vartheta /\vartheta a(a\mathrm{ln}a+(1-a)\mathrm{ln}(1-a))=0\Rightarrow ln(a/(1-a))=0\Rightarrow a=1/2$ which yields only the maximum of $D$ or equivalently the minimum of $a^a(1-a)^{1-a}$. How can I get the other bound?

Comment: Just note that $0<a<1$ implies $a^a\in(0,1)$ and $(1-a)^{1-a}\in(0,1)$.